# Book about a one-armed cowboy who travels across time using a torus (sp?)

Tags: story-identification, books

The elements of the plot that I remember are:

1. One-Armed cowboy spots something weird while out riding (torus, torroid, ?)
2. He breaks a Yale lock using his one hand
3. He travels through time and picks up a caveman
4. They then pick up some others, including alien(s) in whose language God means means devil/god

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's [The Beast](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881848832) by A. E. Van Vogt.

As a teenager I was a huuuuuuuuuuge Van Vogt fan, but I have to say that many of his novels are just short stories bodged together to make a rather incoherent book. The Beast is a prime example of this. I first read (and hugely enjoyed) the short story that forms the first part of the book. When, much later, I found and read the book it was a bit of a let down.

But don't let my somewhat downbeat review of this particular book put you off. If you haven't read any Van Vogt then do so RIGHT NOW!!

Comment: See http://www.andrew-may.com/asf/fixup.htm re Van Vogt's practice of reworking near-perfect short stories into what he referred to as "fix-up novels".

Comment: Bingo! This is a tremendous relief. Thus question has been bothering me for years. Now that my memory has been tickled I am starting to vaguely remember other Van Vogt stories. Off I go to re-read. Adam