# Playing with mental blocks; one-armed protagonist discovers an engine that spins

Tags: story-identification, novel

SF novel which starts with a one-armed main character, who is very strong, out riding his horse and finds a donut shaped engine.  He proceeds to dismount by grabbing the saddle horn with his one hand and lifting himself out of the saddle to investigate.

After an interesting result from jamming a branch in the donut hole he takes it to a shed to investigate.

I can't remember the title or author.  Remember more story if needed although the opening scene is striking enough that I suspect more isn't needed.

Comment: As much as possible is better at finding the story. If you really do remember more please [edit] your question to add everything you remember.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I'm confused by the title of this question (and by the question itself). Is the guy supposed to be a toy or something?

Comment: Sadly, that opening scene may be the best part of the novel.

Comment: Previously asked about in [Book about a one-armed cowboy who travels across time using a torus (sp?)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46782/book-about-a-one-armed-cowboy-who-travels-across-time-using-a-torus-sp)

Comment: —Buzz—   Damon Knight wasn't a fan either.  He thought that Vogt's stories were disjointed or essentially a series of non-sequiters.  Philip K. Dick and Campbell seemed to like him though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This sounds like A.E. van Vogt's fix-up novel [*The Beast*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?14253) (1963).  The episode you describe, which starts the novel, is from his short story ["The Great Engine"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46724) (1943).

The hero is missing an arm, finds the titular engine and discovers that shaft inserted into the hole will spin.

> The blue-gray engine lay half buried in a green hillside.
>
> [...]
>
> There was dirt in its force field, so tightly packed that it would have taken eagle eyes to see how swiftly it was spinning. Not even the boys who sat one day on a flange of the engine noticed the convulsions of the dirt.
>
> [...]
>
> It was more than a week later, late in the afternoon, when a horse climbing the hill straddled the protruding bulge of the engine. The horse's rider proceeded to dismount in an astounding fashion.
>
> With his one hand he grasped the saddlehorn and lifted himself clear of the saddle. Casually, easily, he brought his left leg over, held himself poised in midair, and then dropped to the ground.
>
> [...]
>
> It was awkward work with only a left arm; and so, when he noticed the dirt-plugged hole in the center, he jabbed the wood into it to get better leverage.
>
> His shout of surprise and pain echoed hoarsely on the evening air.
>
> For the wood jerked. Like a shot twisted by the rifled barrel of a gun, like a churning knife, it wrenched in his hand, tearing like a shredder, burning like fire.
>
> He was lifted up, up — and flung twenty feet down the hill. Groaning, clutching his tattered hand to his body, he stumbled to his feet.
>
> The sound died on his lips, then, as his gaze fastened on the throbbing, whirling thing that had been a dead branch of tree.

You can read the 3 original stories in [*Astounding, July 1943*](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v31n05_1943-07_dtsg0318-LennyS/page/n43/mode/2up), [*Astounding, November 1943*](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v32n03_1943-11_dtsg0318/page/n47/mode/2up) and [*Astounding, April 1944*](https://archive.org/details/astoundingv33n02194404.sseric/page/n5/mode/2up) at the Internet Archive.

Comment: Thnx.  I believe you got it.  It sounds like one if his.  His arm regenerates, then looses it again, then regenerates.  This has been warting me for some time.  Again, many thanks.

Comment: So what was the punchline?

Comment: Also here  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/158239/28516 but not accepted.