# Short story about a farmer who unearths a mysterious motor or engine

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, technology

He is working his field and digs up a large object that seems to be humming. There is an opening in the case, so he inserts a piece of lumber and it spins with such torque that it almost kills him. I cannot remember how the story ends. I read it in the mid 1960's.

Comment: Likely a dupe of [Playing with mental blocks; one-armed protagonist discovers an engine that spins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/231221/playing-with-mental-blocks-one-armed-protagonist-discovers-an-engine-that-spins) - "*For the wood jerked. Like a shot twisted by the rifled barrel of a gun, like a churning knife, it wrenched in his hand, tearing like a shredder, burning like fire.*"

Comment: And [Book about a one-armed cowboy who travels across time using a torus (sp?)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46782/book-about-a-one-armed-cowboy-who-travels-across-time-using-a-torus-sp). The original story was The Great Engine, and it was incorporated into a fixup novel called [The Beast](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3244471-the-beast).

Comment: Yes! That is it. Thanks so much. I mixed up the cowboy for a farmer and lot of the rest of the details, but I remember as a teen that the concept of a mysterious engine was so clever.  You guys are great!

Answer (score 6):

The short story is almost undoubtedly "[The Great Engine](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46724)" (1943) by A. E. van Vogt.  It was subsequently used as the first part of the novel [*The Beast*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?14253) (1963).  The story was first published in [*Astounding*, July 1943](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v31n05_1943-07_dtsg0318-LennyS/page/n43/mode/2up) and can be read at the Internet Archive.

> He climbed to the top of the hill and came down again carrying a piece of deadwood about four feet long and three inches in diameter. He began to pry the engine loose from the ground.
>
> It was awkward work with only a left arm; and so, when he noticed the dirt-plugged hole in the center, he jabbed the wood into it to get better leverage.
>
> His shout of surprise and pain echoed hoarsely on the evening air.
>
> For the wood jerked. Like a shot twisted by the rifled barrel of a gun, like a churning knife, it wrenched in his hand, tearing like a shredder, burning like fire.
>
> He was lifted up, up — and flung twenty feet down the hill. Groaning, clutching his tattered hand to his body, he stumbled to his feet.
>
> The sound died on his lips, then, as his gaze fastened on the throbbing, whirling thing that had been a dead branch of tree.

The short story was published in van Vogt's frequently reprinted collection [*Away and Beyond*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?37671) (1952); you can see the [various covers it had](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?37671).